# How to get one result from each groupProperty?

Tags: grails

How can I make a criteria to give one max results from each `groupProperty`?
The results is giving me this

```
[[2, AAA, 333333], [1, AAA, 11111111111111], [1, BBB, 222222222]]
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
[[2, AAA, 333333], [1, BBB, 222222222]]
```

I tried to add maxResults(1), but only returns one results, I thought would be returning ONE result from each groupProperty given.

```
def analysis = Equipment.createCriteria().list{
        'in'('equipment', eqList)
        projections {
            groupProperty "versionHistory"
            groupProperty "analysisParameter"
            groupProperty "identificationCertificate"

        }
        order("versionHistory", "desc")

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *max* function groups. So if you want to get the max `analysisParameter` and `identificationCertificate` for each `versionHistory`, you can do this:

```
def analysis = Equipment.createCriteria().list{
        'in'('equipment', eqList)
        projections {
            groupProperty "versionHistory"
            max "analysisParameter"
            max "identificationCertificate"

        }
        order("versionHistory", "desc")

    }
```

Comment: But why max? its not only for numbers?

Comment: Some databases support `max` on non-numeric columns, so it's not always only for numbers. The max of text/String is the last value if data in the column were sorted in alpha-numerical order, ascending.

Comment: Well I remove the accepted answer because I saw a mistake there.. since I'm trying to get is the max of the versionHistory and not to group them =\

Comment: max "versionHistory", groupProperty "analysisParameter", max identificationCertificate" and remove the order